# Rotation of a pointcloud based on normal vector

Tags: rotation, point-clouds

I'm looking to rotate a 3-D point cloud based on the orientation of the floor.  I have detected the floor and calculated its normal vector.  I want to use this normal vector to ensure that all points on the floor have the same y-value.

Since the dot product of two normalized vectors is the cosine of the angle between them, I first normalize the current normal vector (0.856, 0.958, 2.58) as well as the desired normal vector (0.0, 0.958, 0.0).  The dot product = 0.917 and therefore the angle = 70.586, but being in 3 dimensions this does not seem useful.  Do I need to perform two rotations? If so, are there any suggestions as to the best approach?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a rotation that will transform a normal vector `A` into a desired normal vector `A'`, there are an infinite number of them. (Given one such rotation, you can apply it and then compose it with spins around `A'` to get lots of other rotations that do the same thing.)

One approach that works nicely in 3-D is to compute the cross-product vector `V = A x A'` (which is normal to the plane containing `A` and `A'`) and then rotate around `V` by the angle between `A` and `A'`. (It's important to first test that `A` and `A'` aren't already coincident.)

There's a description of how to do all this fairly efficiently [here](http://www.vtk.org/pipermail/vtkusers/2000-May/050398.html).